# How to identify which common terminal of the 3-way switch is connected the hot wire

Tags: lighting, multiway-switch

The goal is identify hot and neutral wires in a 3-way switched line-array of lights, so that the array can be controlled by an [Acuity SP20 Secondary Relay Pack (bottom device):](https://img.acuitybrands.com/public-assets/catalog/88276/pp20-(sp20).pdf?abl_version=06%2F26%2F2019%2017:36:58&DOC_Type=SPEC_SHEET)

[image]

Said line-array of lights is the only 3-way switched several line-arrays.  The other line arrays are controlled by a single switch.  Said switches form a `bank` of switches at the building entrance.

The target line-array is located between the [two switches](https://youtu.be/_u5ORnhqn8g?t=221):

[image]

Is there any reason to doubt that the wiring diagram above represents how the switches are wired?  or maybe the better question is: How can I confirm that the that the diagram represents said line-array and that the hot and neutral are located at the switch `bank` located at the building entrance?  Diagnostic procedures that are simple / less invasive are preferable

The sub-goal is: How to identify which common terminal of the 3-way switch is connected the hot wire (left 3-way switch) vs, the `switched hot wire` (right 3-way switch)

Comment: Clear pictures of the actual boxes would help this question.

Comment: `Is there any reason to doubt that the wiring diagram above represents how the switches are wired?` ... yes, the diagram shows how the switches **could** be wired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off breaker. Disconnect wires. Connect appropriate meter (safely). Turn on breaker, look at meter. If no voltage, turn off breaker, move to other switch, connect meter, repeat.

Or use a test lamp, if you are old-fangled. The folks around here are fond of "non-contact voltage testers" but they appear to be prone to confusing results. I'm old-fangled enough to prefer a meter, but not old-fangled enough to prefer a test lamp.

If your switches were actually wired "that way" you'd have a neutral connection in one box, and none in the other box. But things are often less clear-cut than that in practice - can't hurt to look for it, though.

Comment: "old-fangled". I like that mashup of "old-fashioned" and "new-fangled". I think I'll borrow that one!

Comment: This old-fangled guy wouldn't be caught dead with a wonder stick (non contact VT). Give me a meter every time.+1

Comment: Yikes!  My preference for a meter puts me in the old-fangled category :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't make sense of any of that German spaghetti.  Here's how 3-way circuits are *actually* wired:

[image]

or

[image]

As well as 3-4 other possible rearrangings-of-furniture, giving the same wires doing the same loop, but on different routings.

> Is there any reason to doubt that the wiring diagram above represents how the switches are wired?

Yeah, lots of reasons to doubt.  3-ways are always the same loop *electrically*... but topologically, there are at least 5 different arrangements by which the wires could be routed.

That is why I favor a functional approach of positively identifying the always-hot, switched-hot, and traveler wires, and marking them as such e.g. with colored tape.

> The sub-goal is: How to identify which common terminal of the 3-way switch is connected the hot wire (left 3-way switch) vs, the switched hot wire (right 3-way switch)

1. 3-way circuit must be working. 2) Measure it. 3) throw a switch. 4) Does it change?

### As usual with smart devices, here is the takeaway:

Smart switches usually need always-hot (black in my diagrams), neutral (white) and often switched-hot (red).  As you can see, this may not exist at some *or any* switch location.

As such, your choice of potential place to put a smart device may be limited, or nonexistent, without a complete reinvention of the circuit using smart tech.

Comment: Interesting diagrams! The wiring inside the light fixture is red and white: reasonable to hypothesize and verify that the red wiring in fixture is switched hot and white is neutral?  How to physically verify?